# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Все очень любят прыгать по лужам - и девочки, и мальчики.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то это предложение с однородными подлежащими и обобщающим словом, поэтому должно стоять двоеточие, но в данной конструкции, учитывая, что обобщающее слово стоит далеко от однородных членов и предложение имеет смысл без них, можно объяснить постановку тире присоединительным характером конца предложения.При желании здесь можно поставить даже точку, применив парцелляцию:

Все очень любят прыгать по лужам.И девочки, и мальчики.

Чтобы однозначно стояло двоеточие, нужно сблизить обобщающее слово и однородные члены: Очень любят прыгать по лужам все: и девочки, и мальчики.

Answer (score 1):

В предложениях с обобщающими словами ударение должно падать на обобщающее слово и члены однородного ряда.

**Вариант 1.**  ВсЕ очень любят прыгать по лужам — и дЕвочки, и мАльчики.

В предложении такой структуры очень сложно сделать предупредительную паузу с понижением голоса пред однородным рядом, поэтому желательно поставить тире **(одно решение).**

**Вариант 2.** (1) По лужам любят прыгать всЕ — и взрослые, и дети. (2) По лужам любят прыгать всЕ: и взрослые, и дети.

В этом случае возможны **оба варианта**, при постановке двоеточия делается увеличенная пауза. Семантика вариантов несколько различна: при постановке тире ряд имеет значение уточнения, о чем сказано у Розенталя:

Если однородные члены предложения носят характер **приложения или уточнения**, то после обобщающего слова вместо двоеточия может ставиться тире: Алый свет нежно заливал окрестности — ветряную мельницу, шиферные крыши машинно-тракторной станции, элеваторы (Кат.). Легенды и сказки любят все — дети и взрослые. [§ 15. Обобщающие слова при однородных членах предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103)